# "PosterBoard quit unexpectedly." warning in my Mac running macOS Ventura 13.4.1(c)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, device, simulator

I don't see any current posts about the warning that says "PosterBoard quit unexpectedly." on my Mac. Older posts say this is an error generated by Xcode Simulator. I tried one of those solutions but I still see this warning coming up. I am also not using Simulator. I'm using an actual device - an iPhone 13 Pro Max running iOS 16.6. When I click on Reopen in that alert box telling me that warning message, I get a warning in an alert box with a picture of the Finder icon on it, and it says "You can’t open the application “PosterBoard.app” because this application is not supported on this Mac.".
Anyone else have this problem and know what do do about it? Like fix it or get around it?